# HTML text align to left with direction rtl

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have JSON object that I display inside a textarea in the HTML as a string.

However, one of the JSON properties has a value that is a mix of Arabic and English words.

```
$scope.result = "{ 
'country' : 'US',
'city': 'New York',
'flight': 'RT232',
'comment':'تأخر الطائرة رقم RT232'
}"  

//Please note that it's a STRING not an object.
```

As you can see, the comment property has Arabic and English letters and it is not correctly formatted, the english part should be at the left not the right.

However, in my HTML I have

```
<textarea>{{result}}</textarea>
```

Now the page shows the string correctly from left to right, but when it comes to the comment part, it shows it wrongly as it is in the string.

So if I do the following :

```
<textarea dir='rtl'>{{result}}</textarea>
```

It shows the string from right to left and everything is messed up, but the comment value is correctly formatted !

Is there a way to display the string from left to right, correctly formatted, with the comment value correctly formatted too ?

Should I handle this in the javascript before passing it to the DOM ?

Note that the string is extremely long with many values like this

**Update** : I wonder if there is a way to transform a sentence using Javascript so that it becomes correct in term of format in case it has latin characters. So that I can iterate over the object, and once I detect a sentence that has Latin characters, I just transform it like this

```
تأخر الطائرة رقم RT232
```

becomes like this:

```
RT232 تأخر الطائرة رقم
```

Comment: try parsing the json into an object and then iterate through it

Comment: It's gonna be hard for many reasons.. I want to display the whole thing including the curly brackets, { ..:{..:[]. The string is soo long with many properties and arrays, this is just a simplified version. I am thinking about a function that changes the redirection of a string in Javascript, so I can do something like Property = changeDirection(Property.value); But I can't see any reference for that online :/

Comment: Not without normalizing the format or adding metadata.

Comment: @cwallenpoole Could you please clarify what you mean ?

Comment: Basically, unless you have a way to know what is a rtl string, there is no way to know that it is formatted incorrectly

Comment: @cwallenpoole Okay assuming that I will parse the string into an object, and iterate over each property to check if the value has arabic characters, let's say a regex function.

Now if it detects it, how can I transform the direction for that property value in the Javascript ?

Comment: check the update part